# pass php array into javascript, check array value and push into new array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am trying to pass 2 php arrays $date_array and $drop_array into javascript so their values can be checked and pushed into a pre existing javascript array.

```
<?php 
$date_array = array('12-08-2016', '12-09-2016', '12-10-2016', '12-12-2016', '12-13-2016', '12-14-2016', '12-15-2016', '12-16-2016', '12-17-2016');
$drop_array = array($drop1, $drop2, $drop3, $drop4, $drop5, $drop6, $drop7, $drop8, $drop9);
?>
```

where $drop1-$drop9 are numeric values. I am currently passing the arrays like this and pushing their values into an array:

```
var date_array = '<?php echo json_encode($date_array); ?>';
var drop_array = '<?php echo json_encode($drop_array); ?>';
var disabledSpecificDays = ["12-11-2016","12-18-2016","12-16-2016","12-17-2016"];
for (var x = 0; x < drop_array.length; x++){
   var j = drop_array[x];
   if (j > 75){
      disabledSpecificDays.push(date_array[x]);
   }
}
```

Currently doing this and adding the dates to the array breaks my calendar. When i dont have this code and just add the dates manually to the array the calendar works fine disables the dates so i think it is how im passing the php values and trying to push them into an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a string with the contents of the JSON rather than an actual JSON array. Remove the single quotes around your PHP tags.

```
var date_array = <?php echo json_encode($date_array); ?>;
var drop_array = <?php echo json_encode($drop_array); ?>;
```

Comment: when i remove the single quotes my closing tags appear to be ignored
`</script>
</body>
</html>`
these tags are usually colored in atom but when i remove the single quotes around php the closing tags turn grey and my calendar doesnt work.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code and the HTML/javascript output it's hard to say...

Comment: `<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" placeholder="Select Date" required/>`
that is the calendar. I'll have to add the function for my calendar in another comment.

Comment: `function disableSpecificDaysAndSundays(date) {
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var y = date.getFullYear();
 for (var i = 0; i < disabledSpecificDays.length; i++) {
  if ($.inArray((m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y, disabledSpecificDays) != -1 || new Date() > date) {
   return [false];
   }
  }
 var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day > 0), true];
 }
$(document).ready(function () {
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  minDate: new Date(2016, 11, 8),
  maxDate: new Date(2016, 11, 17),
  beforeShowDay: disableSpecificDaysAndSundays`

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function so it parses the JSON code created by your Php code. For example:

var date_array = JSON.parse('');

The JSON.parse will convert the JSON string into a Javascript array

Comment: This is incorrect. You could `JSON.parse()` the string (wrapped in single quotes) but that is an unnecessary step if you omit the quotes and have it be a JSON object instead of a string.